# Ordinal predictor treated as continuous in multiple linear regression: testing deviation from linearity with SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data

I am running a multiple linear regression with a continuous DV and a number of independent variables, one of which is ordinal (three-levels).

I am trying to follow David J Pasta’s instructions to evaluate the opportunity of treating the ordinal variable as continuous: [support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/248-2009.pdf]

However, the actual example comes from SAS and I am unable to do the same thing with SPSS (which I am familiar with) or R (which I am learning to use).

He suggests entering both the categorical) and linear (continuous) version of the variable in the same model in order to test the deviation from linearity (I have pasted an excerpt from the paper at the end of the question)

However, when I enter both the categorical variable (coded as two dummy variables) and the linear variable in the model, SPSS drops either the linear variable or one of the dummy variables. The same thing happens if I code the categorical variable as three dummy variables.  I guess this is due to multicollinearity, but maybe I am just doing something silly and I am unaware of it..

*“…Then for each variable you could include both the original (categorical) version and the linear version in the same model! Won't that be redundant? Yes, it will, and the linear version will show up with zero degrees of freedom and not statistical test of significance. The Type III statistical test of the categorical version will have one less degree of freedom than usual and it will be testing the deviation from linearity – whether the remaining K-2 df have statistically significant explanatory power. If the categorical version is statistically significant, that tells you there is a significant non-linear component and it makes sense to omit the linear version of the variable. If the categorical version is not statistically significant by whatever criterion you shoose to use, that means that the linear component carries the explanatory power and the categorical variable can be dropped. (Of course, there's no guarantee that the linear version will be significant after dropping the categorical variable – that still needs to be tested.)”*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like perfect multicollinearity. Try a regression of the linear version of the variable on the dummies. If you get a perfect fit, then you know you have perfect multicolinearity.

Comment: Dear Richard, you are absolutely right. When I regress the linear version on the dummies (2 or 3 makes no difference) I get an R2 of 1. Does this automatically tell me that I am allowed to use the linear version without going through the steps suggested by RJ Pasta? Or is there something else  I can do to follow his suggestion on how to test for deviations from linearity?

Comment: You should not have a set of explanatory variables that are perfectly multicollinear. Kick some out, and then you can continue along the lines suggested by Pasta. (I suppose he did not suggest including multicollinear variables.)

Comment: I am afraid he did... He says "won't that be redundant? Yes it will ..." . I understand that the whole point is using variables that are necessarily multicollinear (categorical and linear version of the same variable). If I remove some I can no longer test what he suggests. But I don't know what to do with perfect multicollinearity. Do you think finding perfect multicollinearity  is already an answer to the question of whether I can treat the ordinal variable as continuous? Since the 2 versions of the variables seem to be "interchangeable" wouldn't they have the same explanatory power?

Comment: You cannot test what you want to if there is perfect multicollinearity. If Pasta thinks you can, he probably got that wrong.

Comment: I have no idea, I was just trying to follow an interesting suggestion on dealing with ordinal predictors that I also found reported elsewhere for logistic regression (https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats3/OrdinalIndependent.pdf). Do I understand correctly that the perfect multicollinearity itself is not already an answer to the question? PS: I am new to the forum: how can I upvote your comments?

Comment: I have tried by omitting d1 but it removes d3 (leaving me with d2 and the linear version). If I omit d2 it removes the linear version. If I omit d3 it again removes the linear version,). Maybe this is very naive, but is there no way of "forcing" them to stay in the model?

Comment: Hmm, I do not think you want a model with perfect multicollinearity. You just don't. I think you have to omit two dummies to avoid that. So if you had an ordinal variable with $K$ categories, you would keep $K-2$ dummies and the linear version, and then you could see whether the dummies are jointly significant. In your case, you only have to see whether the single dummy that you include is significant. Seems quite simple, as SPSS yields significance results for individual variables automatically.

Comment: Yes, it works if I keep a single dummy (and the linear version). The dummy is not significant (whether it is d1, d 2 or d3, taken one at a time).  Would this mean I am allowed to treat my ordinal predictor as continuous (Pasta-way)? Thank you for following-up on my comments with such relentless patience.

Comment: PS: I absolutely don't want a  model with perfect multicollinearity. In fact in my actual model I am using only the linear version as predictor (along with other predictors) and I have a good VIF.  I would have liked to "force" the variables into the exploratory model which would have been used to see whether I was justified in treating my ordinal predictor as continuous (which I do in my actual model). Thank you so much again.

Comment: you are welcome. I was too tired to dig into it deeply yesterday, so I only posted comments, not an answer. But it looks like you got a nice answer from another user.

Comment: SPSS procedure Means tests linearity and deviation from linearity for one-way factor. You may want to look into the Algorithms document.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic full-model/reduced model F test.

1. Fit the model with the dummies (no linear term but all other covariates); this is the "full model." Get the residual sum of squares; call it $SS_f$.
2. Fit the reduced model with only the linear term (and all other covariates); this is the "reduced model." Get the residual sum of squares; call it $SS_r$.

The reduced model is a linear restriction of the full model, so the $F$ test applies.

3. Calculate $$ F = \frac{(SS_r - SS_f)/1}{(SS_f/\nu_f)},$$ where $\nu_f$ is the error degrees of freedom for the full model.  This statistic has the $F_{1,\nu_f}$ distribution under the null hypothesis of a perfectly linear trend, under the usual regression assumptions.
4. Reject the null hypothesis of linearity if $F > F_{1-\alpha, 1, \nu_f}$.

The reason for the numerator df of 1 is that there is one additional parameter in the dummy variable model.

Comment: Dear @BigBendRegion, I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your perfectly clear answer (which I hadn't seen yesterday)

I  have done the calculation by hand and the F statistic is non-significant. I then found  that R has something called Wald’s test for nested models which does the same thing automatically when I input a model with the linear version only and a model with the linear version plus the categorical variables (no problems with variables being kicked out of the model in this case). So, as far as I can see, the “manual” way is the easiest way to do what Pasta suggests in SPSS (apparently no Wald's test for linear regression available there).

If you can still bear with me I have two (possibly stupid) questions to make before I am sure I have understood everything correctly:

a) Would I be allowed to say something like “the ordinal predictor was treated as continuous (and not categorical) in the linear regression based on the non-significance of Wald’s test” ? Or should I be more specific? Like “based on the non-significance of Wald’s test comparing the categorical versus continuous predictor model”? Or something else?

b) The fact that the F statistic is non-significant is telling me that the model treating the ordinal predictor as  a  categorical variable is not a better fit for the data than the model treating it as continuous one (which is the one I am actually using). The assumption of linearity of the regression (which I usually check with a ZRES vs ZPRED plot) is another thing? Or isn’t it?

PS: I apologize for posting this as an answer and not as a comment but the word limit was too strict. Of course, I am willing to edit/delete anything you feel is not appropriate for the forum.

Comment: (a) Looks ok.  I might say "deviations from linearity are explainable by chance alone, based on the Wald test..." or something like that.   (b) The ordinal model is not a discernably better fit. As far as the linearity assumption, it refers to the entire model, but this test is just a part of all that.  So this is a test for linearity with respect to this particular X.